# second d3.js triggered from first doesn't fully iterate over X axis

Tags: javascript, triggers, d3.js

Folks -

I'm now trying to trigger a second chart based on which series in the first chart is clicked on.

Based on which is chosen, one of two data sets are sent to the function:

```
.on("mouseup", function(d) {return d.myCat == 0 ? updateData(yesXYZData) : updateData(nonXYZData)})
```

This part works, but I'm getting one big stack in the target div, not the iteration I am expecting.

```
function updateData(whichDataSet) {...
```

I've tried putting the updateData() function into the window.onload function, duping or reusing various elements (since the domain and range for the X axis are the same, I expect to  reuse).

[Note- I have taken Lars Kothoff's advice regarding numbers in the data object. Also, I will create a better data structure later, using crossfilter.js and native d3.js data manipulation- for now I need a working prototype demonstrating functionality.]

here is the gist:

https://gist.github.com/RCL1/6906892

Thanks in advance!

-RL

Comment: What do you mean by iteration? What is your function supposed to do and what actually happens?

Comment: It should create a similar chart to the initial one, but based on the data set passed to it. Instead, I get one very wide stack. It looks like it's not calculating the x axis. I have great difficulty in debugging d3.js due to its non-linear nature, making it difficult to watch what's happening during creation.

Comment: gist reference added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 242 of the gist. I needed to use a non-filtered version of the data to calculate x axis (totalAll.map).